# Getting rid of whitespace in upper part of excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have pasted text into a cell of an excel spreadsheet but there is lots of white-space above this text making the cell almost twice the size it needs to be.  Clicking on backspace does nothing to move the text up?  What can I do to get rid of this white-space?  What is it doing there? And why does backspace/delete not remove anything? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly might be causing your problem, but since it's not from the text itself, it's probably due to the formatting. And that depends on the source of the text you have pasted. The easiest way is to paste the text into `notepad` to strip everything but the text and then copy from notepad into excel. You can also try the **Paste Special** option in excel. In the dialog that pops up, choose *Text*.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, follow Nithin's answer.

I'm taking a guess that when you pasted the text, Excel made the row taller.  Double-click the row header between the tall row and the next one (eg. if row 2 is tall, double-click between the number 2 and number 3 on the left.)

The other formatting that may be applied is "Wrap Text".  This can be turned off by selecting all cells, pressing "Format Cell", opening the "Alignment" tab, and turning off "Wrap Text".

Answer (score 0):

For Mac: 
Right click on the cell from which you want extra space removed - Click on Formatting cell- click on alignment -  click on the "top"from droop down menu. This should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Nithin Philips said: "...paste the text into notepad to strip everything but the text and then copy from notepad into excel..."

I did this and found that there were quotation marks in the text. I removed the marks then pasted back to Excel. Voila! No more spaces!